# General time range with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do something in SQL and I just can't figure out how I should do that. I have this table

```
 ----------------------------------
 |id_visit | visit_date | ssn     |
 ----------------------------------
 |1        |1940-01-07  |123125789|
 ----------------------------------
 |2        |1975-03-15  |987743271|
 ----------------------------------
 | ...     |  ...       | ...     |
```

and I need to select SSN's of patients that were visited more than five times within a year. How do I do that? I know it involves a 'HAVING COUNT(id_visit)' but for time part... that's a different story because my goal isn't to select ssn's in a specific time range but within a general range.

From @Gordon Linoff answer, I modified the query a bit for eliminating repetition in the results and getting maximum result only.

```
 select p_ssn as SSN, max(visits_within_one_year) as "Maximum number of visits" 
 from (select t.p_ssn,count(*) as visits_within_one_year
         from t join
              t tyr
              on t.p_ssn = tyr.p_ssn and
              tyr.visit_date between t.visit_date and adddate(t.visit_date, 365)
              group by t.p_ssn,t.visit_date 
              having visits_within_one_year > 5)results
 group by p_ssn;
```

Comment: Do you want to have it within a calender year, or within a rolling year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean calendar year, the following query retrieves all SSNs and year combinations where the SSN appears more than five times during the year:

```
select ssn, year(visit_date) as yr
from t
group by ssn, year(visit_date)
having count(*) > 5;
```

If the question is about an arbitrary year period, then you can use a self join and aggregation:

```
select t.ssn, t.visit_date, count(*) as visits_within_one_year
from t join
     t tyr
     on t.ssn = tyr.ssn and
        tyr.visit_date between t.visit_date and adddate(t.visit_date, 365)
group by t.ssn, t.visit_date
having visits_within_one_year > 5;
```

Comment: I'm thinking for the second query, you may need to group on t.visit_date as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My question was about an arbitrary year period. It worked out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to get those ssn within a solar year (jan/dec):

```
select ssn
from tablename
group by ssn,year(visit_date)
having count(ssn)>5
```

Comment: Guess this assumes it is within a calender year. (1 jan-31 dec) --Techincality: Should be more than 5 rather than `>4`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin ops a typo

Comment: In MySQL `WHERE` clauses are executed before `SELECT`, therefore, aggregate functions don't work in `WHERE` clauses. Instead, use `HAVING`.